# Existence of a convergent power series to satisfy an equation

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

The problem below is an early textbook activity (Chapter 2, having only defined power series and discussed the basics). I can solve the problem by using Taylor series of $\sqrt{1+x}$ and the quadratic formula, but I'm having trouble solving it using more basic techniques. I believe it should be done using only power series and the relation between coefficients and using root test (to show the radius of convergence is positive.)

> Let $a \in \mathbb{C}$. Show that there is a power series $f(z) = z + c_2z^2+c_3z^3+ \cdots$ with positive radius of convergence $r$, such that,
> $$f(z) + a [f(z)]^2 =z$$
> on $|z|<r$.

Comment: $c_2=-a$, $c_3=-2ac_2=2a^2$, $c_4=-a(2c_3+c_2^2)=-5a^3$  See if there is a pattern.

Comment: You can get rid of $a$ by letting $g(z)=af(z)$ and $w=az$ and expressing the problem in terms of $g(w)$.

Comment: @herb steinberg - That's the issue - there is is no apparent pattern, nor is there one for bounds on coefficients to approximate the radius of convergence

Comment: @Micheal Hartley - thank you, but I don't see that going anywhere. Do you having something in mind using this?